# Create one exe file with buil-in static libraries

Tags: c, eclipse, opencv, makefile

I have project in openCV, created as Makefile application under eclipse (MinGW/Windows 8 os). I need to create one executable file so that there won't be required any other dlls while running app on other computer without openCV installed.

I have also compiled openCV sources as static library. That is what my Makefile (draft) looks like:

```
all:    
    gcc -static -I"C:\opencv\build\include" -L"lib" main.c -lws2_32 -lopencv_core244.dll -lopencv_highgui244.dll -lopencv_imgproc244.dll -o bcast.exe
```

After building exec doesn't contain libs. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're expected to link `*.lib` files, not `*.dll` (***Dynamic***-Link Library).

So, that should be :

```
g++ -I"C:\opencv\build\include" -L"lib" main.c -lws2_32 -lopencv_core244.lib -lopencv_highgui244.lib -lopencv_imgproc244.lib -o bcast.exe
```

(You should consider using g++ for this, it's a c++ library.) After that your makefile will produce 1 `.exe` file, no libs.

Honestly, did you *really* recompile the opencv libs statically (with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`)? I'm having doubts here.

Comment: I meant that there are no libraries included in exe file.
I will try to recompile openCV one more time.

Comment: I did what You told me but I've got error while compiling openCV app:
`g++ -static "-LC:\\MinGW\\lib" "-LC:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\mingw_static\\lib" -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o qwasegf.exe main.o -lws2_32 -lopencv_core248 -lopencv_highgui248 -lopencv_imgproc248 
    C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw_static\lib\libopencv_core248.a(persistence.cpp.obj): bad reloc address 0x40 in section '.text$_ZL6icvEofP13CvFileStorage'
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation`